# Use component parameter inside Angular's index template (index.html page)

Tags: angular

In my angular project, **index.html** has been defined as index page through the `angular.json` configuration

**index.html code**

```
<body>
  <app-root>
    <div> Application Title: </div>
  </app-root>
</body>
```

I need to call a parameter in the `index.html` template from a component (let's say from AppComponent whose selector is `app-root`) so my page would be like this

```
<body>
  <app-root>
    <div> Application Title: {{title}} </div>
  </app-root>
</body>
```

However **index.html** page is the project's index page and not managed by any angular component so I could not use any of the traditional ways to pass parameters between components (shared injected services, @Input and @Output member variables between the components etc.)

Is there any way to achieve my scenario?

Comment: You can create a separate component that holds the title and create a service to update the title. This is the way.

Comment: Why just not moving your <div> Application Title: {{title}} </div> at top of the template of your AppComponent ?

Comment: @BenoitCuvelier this div is shown while the application is loading so it has to be in the index.html file

Comment: @Eldar that's a good idea I do not see any other option too but I thought maybe there would be a more 'direct' way, thank you very much

Comment: @Eldar I tried to create a new component and include the index's html code inside like this

`<app-root> <loading-page> </loading-page> </app-root>`

but now the html code that moved from the index.html to the `loading page` is not displayed at all, I guess this has to do with the fact that before angular loads all the components it shows the html in the `index.html` page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After an unsuccesful try of packaging  `<div> Application Title: </div>` inside a component named `loading-page` and showing there the variable of title, I solved my case by writing js code inside a `<script>` tag in the index.html file

More specifically, what I needed was before load of the application, fetch from `electron settings` the title of the application and show it during loading of the application, code example below:

**index.html** code

```
<body>
  <app-root>
    <div id="title"> Application Title: </div>
    <script>
        const settings = require('electron-settings');
        const titleProperty = settings.getSync('title').toString();
        const title = document.getElementById('title');
        title.textContent = 'Application Title: ' + titleProperty
    </script>
  </app-root>
</body>
```

This way, I fetch from the electron settings the name of the application and then change the text content of the div with id `title` in a way that is shown